# LibGdx - Cannot create a server socket/ "Adress already in use"

Tags: android, sockets, networking, libgdx, port

I'm building an app in LibGdx and is a two players game. I'm using libgdx sockets and every time I return to the Main Menu, supposedly, I free the sockets by calling them dispose(). But it's not working and it keeps telling me that the address is already in use.
help :/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1NzS.png)

Comment: Can you post your code so we can take a look? I'm guessing it has to do with the way you're changing screens.